# Python Multiprocessing .start() issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, raspberry-pi3, python-idle

I am trying to use multiprocessing to speed up my process time when controlling a stepper motor but whenever I try and start the process (*t1.start()*) I get a pop-up window stating

"Kill? 
Your program is still running!
Do you want to kill it?"

[image: Pop up window]

If I select either option my action does not happen.
I have simplified my code down to the following to troubleshoot the issue.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def simple():
    sim = True

def startrun():
    t1 = mp.Process(target=simple, args=())
    t1.start()
    t1.join()


print("Start in 5 seconds")
time.sleep(5)
startrun()

print("While loop in 5 seconds")
time.sleep(5)
while 1:
   i=0
```

I am doing this on a *Raspberry Pi 3B V1.2*

I have recently updated and upgraded Pi, Python, multiprocessing

I can get the above code to work with threading in place of multiprocessing but that does not help my speed issues.

I am using *Python IDLE 3.5.3*

[image: Python IDLE info]

Comment: AFAIK IDLE doesn't work with multiprocessing. Run it from terminal or switch to an IDE like PyCharm (community version is free) for example.

Comment: Ok so that was my issue. I switched to Thonny

Comment: @Darkonaut   AFAIK, current multiprocessing works fine with current IDLE (3.7.2/3.8.0a from python.org) at least on Windows and likely Linux, especially if one starts IDLE in the console/terminal.  Both have gotten several bugfixes since 3.5.3.  On Windows, multiprocessing calls must be contained within the body of an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement.  When I add the guard, and add `print('done')` at the end of `simple`, the code runs until interrupted.  I only see the kill warning when I try to close Shell.  This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy I just checked with Python 3.7.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I get the same message about killing as soon as  `startrun()` is about to run. IDLE was started from terminal.

Comment: Travis, it appears that the code above is in a file `Multi.py`.  It appears that you got an interactive `>>>` prompt after an exception (the barely visible red ).  You imported Multi and it printed the 'Start' message.  Some time later, the warning popped up.  Did you click or hit a key before that?    If not, the pop-up was a bug since fixed, an effect of the RPi environment, or an effect of the interaction before the import.

Comment: @Darkonaut Thank you for the response.  I will have to ask another core dev with ubuntu to run some experiments.

Comment: Terry, Yes Mult.py is how I called the above code in IDLE. after hitting enter to  import my code I had no other interaction before the "kill?" window was displayed.